# What network/device info can be obtained from an iOS device connected to an 802.11u-enabled access point?

Tags: wifi, ios, access-point, 802.1

In order to perform some device security validations, I need canonical references to what device/hardware/network information can be obtained from an iOS device connected to an [802.11u](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11u)-enabled access point.

There are of course your typical network details:

- MAC
- Hostname (e.g. "Fred's iPhone")

Are there other details about the device that can obtained, such as UDID, IMEI, or even the currently connected carrier details? If so, please provide suitable references.

Answer (score 1):

In my company we have many access points, all managed by [NAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Access_Control) Gateways.

We manage 2 types of devices :

1. BYOD devices (Bring Your Own Device)
2. Corporate devices

Informations we actually obtain for (1) are :

- Wifi IP Address
- Wifi MAC Address
- Device family (e.g Apple iOS, not the version and no distinction between
  iPhone,iPad,iPod,ATV)
- Hostname
- Username (once connected to the network)

For (2), the approach is a bit different as we use an enrollement process (actually [Airwatch](http://www.air-watch.com/us/)) that installs an agent on the device. From here we are able to get these infos, in addition to the previous ones we already have :

- Device model (e.g iPhone 4S GSM/CDMA 16 GB Black)
- iOS version
- Telephone number (if any, depending on device)
- Serial number
- UDID
- Power source (battery/plugged and % battery charge fill)
- Storage capacity (and % used/available)
- Physical memory (and % used/available)
- All apps installed on the device
- Certificates installed
- IMEI
- Telecom operator name
- Telecom operator version
- SIM ID
- Bluetooth MAC Address
- MCC/MNC
- email address(es)

These infos (2) are synchronised to the NAC Gateways.

This is just my experience...not **the** ultimate answer. Hope you will find it interesting.